# How to Solve for Exponential Variable

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

How does one solve for $M$ given:

$$
\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^m \leq N\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^M
$$

As I understand it, the (desired) "final" form is:

$$M \leq \frac{1}{log\frac{4}{3}}(m + log N) \leq 2.41(m + log N) $$

I have tried:

1. $$m\log \frac{1}{2} \leq \log N + \log(\frac{3}{4})^M$$
2. $$\displaystyle\frac{m  \log \frac{1}{2} - \log N}{\log \frac{3}{4}} \leq M$$

Comment: What else do you want to solve?It's enough for this inequation

Comment: It is unclear how your second answer isn't acceptable. What more are you hoping for?

Comment: @JaideepKhare I'd like to solve for M and recast the inequality as shown in the updated post (see desired "final" form). Thanks.

Comment: If you got to 2) and the final form was supposed to be "final form" then an arithmetic error was made, either by you or the book.  But the method you did to get 2) is just fine.  An arithmetic error was made somewhere.  Those aren't worth explaining.  Try it again and see if you can catch it.

Comment: Your inequality $(2)$ is incorrect because you forgot to reverse the sense of the inequality when you divided by the negative number $\log\frac{3}{4}$.

Comment: The "desired" form is also incorrect since the $\log(2)$ factor of $m$ is missing. Perhaps that was simply omitted by accident?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^m \leq N\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^M$

$1 \le N*3^M*2^{m - 2M}$

$0 \le \log N + M\log 3 +(m-2M)\log 2$

$-\log N - m\log2 \le M(\log 3-2\log 2)$; $\log 3 < \log 4$

$-\frac {\log N + m\log 2}{\log 3 - 2\log2} = \frac {\log N + m\log 2}{2\log 2 - \log3}\ge M$

$\frac {\log N + m\log 2}{\log \frac 43} \ge M$

Which seems to me to be far enough.

I'd actually prefer it as $\frac{\log 2^mN}{\log\frac 43}\ge M$ but that's just my taste.

Knowing $\frac 1{\log 43} > 3.47$

We can do $3.47(\log N + m\log 2) < \frac {\log N + m\log 2}{\log \frac 43} \ge M$ but I honestly don't see the point of such approximation.

Anyway... I'm not getting your texts answer.

Comment: The "final" form provided by the text very well maybe wrong; I'll investigate and update. However, with respect to your solution, how do you get to: $1 \leq N * 3^M * 2^{m-2M}$... I understand that you multiplied both sides by $2^m$, to get $1 \leq N * (\frac{3}{4})^M * 2^m$... but then?

Comment: $(\frac 34)^M*2^m= 3^M *( \frac 14)^M=3^M*2^{-2M}*2^m = 3^M*2^{m - 2M}$.  I didn't need to do it and in the end I turned it back.  But to manipulate results I wanted to consolidate.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. However, how would you do it without the manipulation? I understand that dividing by $log \frac{3}{4}$ should flip the inequality (see post step 2), but it is still not equivalent to your answer.

Comment: Any manipulation will do.  Just watch out for negative values of logs.